# Regex and remove not working properly

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, matching

I have some doubts about what I'm doing. I try to remove pices of text like the letter "n" where it is between a "(" and a " " or viceversa, and many other cases. I use regex to find the pattern, but how can I delete only the letter?

I've used this:   `"[( ]" + mystring + @"[)= \-\*]"`

like this:

```
foreach(Match mm in Regex.Matches(SourceCode, @"[( ]" + mystring + @"[)= \-\*]"))
{   
    int lng= mm.Length;
    SourceCode = SourceCode.Remove(mm.Index + 1, lng- 2);
}
```

The problem is that it calculates the index for the original text, and if there will be removed a "n" the index for the next match will be decalated with one and will delete from a wrong place. Really strange.

Does anybody know what it is doing that?

Or maybe do you have a better ideea?

**Edit:**

I can't use replace. Let's say I want to delete "n" where n is like "(n " so if I use replace it will delete all those three characters wich I don want. If I use replace only for n, it will delete wrong letter like the "n" from "and" . . .

Comment: how about storing the index in a var each time you gogin to change something?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker's solution will kee[ the ( and the space.

Comment: As for your edit: Yes, you can use replace. The lookaround assertions only make sure that the surrounding characters are there, but they won't be part of the match and therefore won't be replaced. Try my answer and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to read, but I think what you need is a replace operation, together with [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
SourceCode = Regex.Replace(SourceCode, "(?<=[( ])" + mystring + "(?=[)= *-])", "");
```

This will replace the regex `mystring` with nothing, but only if it is preceded by a `(` or space, and followed by `)`, `=`, `*`, `-` or space.

If you want `mystring` to be interpreted as a string, not as a regex, you should use `Regex.Escape(mystring)` instead of `mystring`.

Comment: ahh, that's exactlly what I was looking for. Thank you so much, and sorry for my bad english!